# Display section of content by IFrame (Angular 5)

Tags: angular, iframe

I am using IFrame to insert the content from other source into my application. I have followed few online stuff and have successfully implemented responsive iframe using Bootstrap.

Currently, the IFrame is fetching the complete content. But I want to just fetch some part of the content.

I tried the code below and IFrame is responsive but the content fetched changes each time when loaded on different systems. How can I set the section of the content to be displayed by IFrame so that it will be uniform over all systems.

**main.component.html**

```
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" [src]='url' 
    scrolling="no" style="margin-top: -180px; height: 730px; width:96%;"> 
  </iframe>  
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "some part of the content"?

Comment: the iFrame load an url, the full page is always rendered. You mean that you want just some part of that url to be rendered?

Comment: Currently, IFrame is fetching complete external webpage, but I want only some part of that webpage to be seen in my application(For e.g I just want the content in the middle of external webpage to be seen and the remaining content is not seen)